# Getting Timer error

Tags: ios, objective-c

After creating an image at a random location (spawnGood), if that object collides with the user controlled image (userToken) an NSTimer should start to work which uses the 'stick' method. This method is supposed to move spawnGood to the same position as userToken if userToken is moved (eg. sticks itself to userToken). However, I get the 'unrecognised selector sent to instance' error when the two images collide. It may either be a problem with the timer or the method, so is anyone able to suggest a solution to this? Thanks in advance :)

The code below produces the described error:

```
-(void)spawn{

    spawn = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(spawnMechanism)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}



-(void)stick:(UIImageView *)spawnGood{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                          delay: 0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         spawnGood.center=CGPointMake(userToken.center.x, userToken.center.y);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"complete");
                     }];



}




-(void)spawnMechanism{
    timeSinceLastSpawn++;


    if(timeSinceLastSpawn >= 3)
    {
        if( arc4random() % 10 < 7 ){


            UIImageView *spawnGood;

            spawnGood=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random() % 700, -100, 70,70)];
            UIImage *image;
            image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"friendly-01"];
            [spawnGood setImage:image];
            [array addObject:spawnGood];
            [self.view addSubview:spawnGood];

            NSLog(@"spawnGood spawned");
            [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                  delay: 0.0
                                options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                             animations:^{
                                 CGRect frame1 =[spawnGood frame];

                                 frame1.origin.y =frame1.origin.y+950;
                                 [spawnGood setFrame:frame1];

                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                 if(CGRectIntersectsRect(userToken.frame, spawnGood.frame)){
                                     NSLog(@"Good Collision");
                                     stick=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:rate
                                                                            target:stick
                                                                          selector:@selector(stick:)
                                                                          userInfo:nil
                                                                           repeats:YES];














                                 }else{
                                     [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
                                         CGRect frame1 =[spawnGood frame];

                                         frame1.origin.y =frame1.origin.y+950;
                                         [spawnGood setFrame:frame1];
                                     }
                                                      completion:nil];

                                     };
                             }



             ];


        }










            }





        }
```

Comment: Some more details about the error would really help here.  Usually the unrecognized selector errors say *which* selector was unrecognized.  What does your error say?

Comment: In full it is "-[__NSCFTimer stick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98208a0"

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors:

1. the target in this line

   ```
                               stick=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:rate
                                                                       target:stick
                                                                     selector:@selector(stick:)
                                                                     userInfo:nil
                                                                      repeats:YES];
   ```

   should be 'self', not 'stick' (which is presumably an NSTimer * class variable?)
2. the parameter of stick should be an NSTimer *, not an image view.

You should prettify your code and add more context.

Comment: The error ("[FIVESContentViewController stick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98a3d80" still seems to be there even after changing to self and adding NSTimer parameter...